# Refresh a Lightning Web Component when fields of a lead record are edited

Tags: lightning-web-components, refreshapex

Is there a way to refresh a lightning web component after a record has been edited?

I have a LWC on a lead record layout, and I want the LWC to be refreshed when I edit fields in that lead record without having to click the refresh button of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

try using lightning-record-edit-form. it will automatically refresh the form when you hit save.[record edit form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation)